# Some files aren't downloaded completely when using curl

Tags: php, curl

I need to download a backup file from one webserver to another using curl. But I have some restrictions:

1. I don't have shell and/or ftp access  to none of the servers.
2. This solution should work even if the domain is not pointed to the source server

Here is example of what I am talking about:

let's assume that example.com exist on server with IP address: 1.1.1.1 while the domain itself is pointed to some other IP address (say 2.2.2.2).

I know that there is some archive on 1.1.1.1 server in example.com folder

I have created some test code which seem to work for files that takes several hundreds KB, but it doesn't work for file which takes ~600MB and I cannot detect the problem.

Does curl in this case download the file into RAM or it reads data in chunks like copy function? If it downloads the data in RAM first, is there some solutions of doing the exact thing that this wget does: "wget --header='Host: example.com' http://1.1.1.1/a.tar"?

```
function get_file( $domain, $path_to_remote_file, $ip, $f_out )
{
    $url = "http://" . $domain . "/" . $path_to_remote_file;
    $handle = fopen($f_out, "w");
    $ch = curl_init( $url );

    curl_setopt( $ch, 
           CURLOPT_RESOLVE, 
           array (
                    $domain . ":80:" . $ip,
                    "www." . $domain . ":80:" . $ip
        ) 
    );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $handle );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);

    $result = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    fclose( $handle );

    echo $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with curl, wget, dns or file size. Maybe is the time of your PHP script.

You can try enabling PHP LOGs and check why your script are stopping. Then, you can try to use `set_time_limit(0)`. Be careful, is you are using a shared hosting, maybe admins warning you about time.

A good solution for your problem: use a worker or cron job. For example, plesk and cpanel has modes to run a PHP with `php-cli`, without any http request.